# Android string-array from xml file to ListView

Tags: android, arrays, xml, listview

First of all, thank you for your answers! I'm new for Android and this is my problem;

I want to take values of string array to listview.

Program works fine with these codes:

```
private String [] fiilliste={"A","Ağlamak","Almak","B","Bulmak"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fiilliste);
vlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I wanna use xml file for string-array. This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

     <string-array name="fi">
        <item>A</item>
      <item>Almak</item>
      <item>Anlamak</item>
      <item>Anlasmak</item>
      <item>Anlatmak</item>
      <item>Ayrilmak</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and I just changed the code with following code, and now program doesn't work.

```
String [] fiilliste= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fi);
```

Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank you!

Activity codes:

```
package com.gazi.tezproje;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class verbs extends Activity {

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        ActionBar bar=getActionBar(); 
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        MenuInflater menu1 = getMenuInflater();
        menu1.inflate(R.menu.info, menu);


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuinfo:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.verbs), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break; 
            case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private ListView vlist;
    EditText ara;

    String [] fiilliste= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fi);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verbs);

        vlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fiilliste);

        vlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        ara = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        vlist.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ara.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                /* When user changed the Text */
                verbs.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                /*TODO Auto-generated method stub*/
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
                /*TODO Auto-generated method stub*/
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the activity code full and where do you have this `String [] fiilliste= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fi);`?

Comment: check my post now and try

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Change to

```
String [] fiilliste;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verbs);
    fiilliste = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fi); 
    // move this in onCreate
```

I assume you have the string array fi in `strings.xml`.

You probably got `NullPointerException`. You require activity context for `getResources()`. So move it inside `onCreate`.

Answer (score 22):

here is what I did. i have created a string-array in array.xml

```
 <resources>
<string-array name="numbers">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
</string-array>
```

and put a lisView in my xml layout

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

here is my MainActivity look like.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView listView;
String[] number;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    number = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, number);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, textView.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: android entries is not required in xml file.

Comment: yes, I have removed entries from xml, Thanks @Minion,

Answer (score 2):

remove `android:entries` from your .xml file & define the string array into

```
String[] number = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.numbers);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the code should be put in on create or any other function. Not as static variable

Comment: I meant that the value doesn't get in runtime